# How do I convert img url into blob object file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blob

I'm trying to convert the img link into blob. I want to send the blob as the object file, currently I got the blob as [object HTMLImageElement]. How do I fix this and send it as blob [object File] ?

This is what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

```js
var myImage;
fetch('https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/4hL2bA5OUf0lSqR2WlY9ogSYtTE=/152x62:1340x953/920x613/filters:focal(615x92:829x306):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/66220207/the_child_star_wars_gallery_5e3204be4f668.0.jpg')
  .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
  .then(blob => {

    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = objectURL;

    console.log(myImage);
  });

$("#approve").click(function() {
  var logoFilename = myImage;
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('logo', logoFilename);
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="approve" name="approve" class="btn btn-success">Approve</button>
```

Comment: save `blob` to some outerscope variable so that your approve callback can access it

Comment: How do I do that ? I don't quite get it about the outerscope variable ?

Comment: It is like your `myImage` variable it is outside your callback function so it is in a outer scope. Just make a new variable like `myBlob` and set it in your callback, eg `myBlob=blob`

Comment: if you dont mind could you show it ? Because I'm not quite sure in the callback ? I did it in my callback like this example `myBlob=blob` and I got `lDev:1589 Uncaught ReferenceError: blob is not defined`

Comment: `.then(blob => { myBlob=blob; `